# Can you use an adjective after a noun?

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives

> I got it *in **years former***.

Can you use an adjective after a noun in this way?

*I* (pronoun, subject)
*got* (verb, transitive)
*it* (pronoun, direct object)...

After that I do not understand what the words are, maybe a prepositional phrase? Can you use an adjective after a noun like this?

Comment: I is a pronoun; and it is not an object here, it is a subject... I also think you need to clarify your question in the last sentence a bit.

Comment: See ["matters spiritual" versus "spiritual matters"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52370/matters-spiritual-vs-spiritual-matters) and the link to [Why do some adjectives follow the nouns they modify?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42319/) on ELU.

Comment: *\*In years former*, no. *In years past*, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it is normally seen as a self-consciously "poetic" construction:

"I sing the body electric" - Whitman

although a few relatively common figures of speech follow the pattern, such as

"the body politic" and "times past".